# VS Code connect ENOENT error MacOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, enoent

A previously stable `VS Code` install is now broken. Whenever I click on the 'Extensions' icon, I get this error message, and no extensions are listed.

```
connect ENOENT /var/folders/my/t5b899fn0_s4tx5_tndwnvh00000gp/C/Code-1.16.1-shared.sock
```

My system:

```
MacOS 10.12.6
VS Code - latest
```

Reinstalling the app does not help. I removed the app bundle, the `~.vscode` directory and the `/Users/gillespy/Library/Application\ Support/Code` directory.

I have 2 VPN services installed:

- TunnelBear
- F5 SSL VPN Plugin (a VPN service for my university, which
  I need)

VS Code worked fine with TunnelBear, but not after the F5 plugin was installed (maybe a coincidence). Neither VPN is active when I open VS Code.

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found.

The .sock file listed in the error message does not exist. Hence the ENOENT error.

Installing 1.16.1, 1.15.1, 1.14.2 results in the same error with the appropriate version number in the .sock file.

Version 1.13.1 works correctly. So I have downgraded and turned off auto update. I'll file a bug report shortly.